# Ubuntu compatibility with ASUS VivoBook N580VD

Tags: laptop, asus, compatibility

I was looking for a powerful Notebook and found the Asus VivoBook  N580VD-DM070T. I've done some research about problems with Ubuntu, but could not find anything for this model. Does anyone have experience with Ubuntu on this model?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Asus N580VD with Windows 10 for some time. Today I had some time to install Ubuntu 17.10 and test. Everything works OK, except one little glitch: I can't power off or reboot without manually holding power button pressed, when I pick power off from the UI or run `poweroff` from terminal, all applications close, TTY comes up but then it hangs. I've been doing some research but couldn't figure out the reason or the solution, yet.

Comment: thanks for you answer, if you have more information about the solution of the problems please say me, because I'm interested in this laptop, but I need to use ubuntu

Comment: Do you use both OS? i.e dual boot?

Comment: No, I am using only Ubuntu (for now 17.10) on that notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (but now it is too late) to no to buy this model. It has a BIOS deeply customized, Ubuntu 17 doesn't work well, the computer is not able to logout properly (I don't know if it's a problem of the Ubuntu version or of the hardware), and if you want to log out you cant't, the screen gets stuck. This happened after the attemp to install lkde desktop. I also think that there is not fully compatibility with the hardware monitor, because I've experienced some problem visualizations, but I don't know if it all comes after the installation of lkde dektop environment. And, after three months of usage, this laptop stopped to work, there is a component that gets hot when you plug-in the battery.  I suggest to not to buy this laptop, because I think that there is not fully compatibility with Ubuntu 17.